# Iterating over data structure

Tags: perl, data-structures, iterator, complex-data-types

I am trying to iterate over this data structure:

```
$deconstructed->{data}->{workspaces}[0]->{workspace}->{facts}[0]->{code}
```

where `fact[0]` is increasing.  It's several files I am processing so the number of `{facts}[x]` varies.

I thought this might work but it doesn't seem to be stepping up the `$iter` var:

```
foreach $iter(@{$deconstructed->{data}->{workspaces}[0]->{workspace}->{facts}}){
  print $deconstructed->{data}->{workspaces}[0]->{workspace}->{facts}[$iter]->{code}."\n";
}
```

I'm totally digging data structures but this one is stumping me. Any advice what might be wrong here?

Comment: `$iter` already *is* what you're trying to get at. Just do `print $iter . "\n"`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$iter is being set to the content of each item in the array *not* the index. e.g.

```
my $a = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
for my $i (@$a) {
    print "$i\n";
}
```

...prints:

```
a
b
c
```

Try:

```
foreach $iter (@{$deconstructed->{data}->{workspaces}[0]->{workspace}->{facts}}){
    print $iter->{code}."\n";
}
```

Comment: Unk, you're the first so you get the karma. All these answers have been great! Janie

Comment: You can give upvotes to every answer you like and check the answer that solved your problem first/best as correct.

Comment: Upvoting you too Mugen! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`$iter` is not going to be an index that you can subscript the array with, it is rather the current element of the array. So I guess you should be fine with:

```
$iter->{code}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your $iter contains the data sctructure. What you basiclly want is:

```
foreach my $elem ( @{$deconstructed->{data}->{workspaces}[0]->{workspace}->{facts}} ){
    print $elem->{code};
}
```

or:

```
foreach my $iter ( 0 .. scalar @{$deconstructed->{data}->{workspaces}[0]->{workspace}->{facts}} ){
    print $deconstructed->{data}->{workspaces}[0]->{workspace}->{facts}[$iter]->{code}."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are looping over the array, your misnamed `$iter` is the value you are looking for, not an index.
If you want to loop over the indexes instead, do:

```
foreach $iter ( 0 .. $#{$deconstructed->{data}->{workspaces}[0]->{workspace}->{facts}} ) {
    print "Index $iter: ",
        $deconstructed->{data}->{workspaces}[0]->{workspace}->{facts}[$iter]->{code}."\n";
}
```

Also note that you can drop `->` between two `[]` or `{}`:

```
$deconstructed->{data}{workspaces}[0]{workspace}{facts}[$iter]{code}
```

I recommend reading http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference.

Answer (score 0):

When you have ugly data structures like this, make an interface for it so your life is easier:

```
 foreach my $fact ( $data_obj->facts ) {  # make some lightweight class for this
     ....;
     }
```

Even without that, consider using a reference to just the part of the data structure you need so you don't think about the rest:

```
 my $facts = $deconstructed->{data}{workspaces}[0]{workspace}{facts};
 foreach my $fact ( @$facts ) {
     print "Thing is $fact->{code}\n";
     }
```

It's just a reference, so you're not recreating anything. Since you only have to think about the parts beyond the `facts` key, the problem doesn't look as hard.